# Swift 2.0 UIImagePickerController dismissing parent view on close

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, swift2

Started developing an app in Xcode 6.* using a pre-2.0 version of swift. Since updating to Xcode 7.0 ans swift 2.0, my application isn't behaving as expected.

In my application I have a typical user settings view that get's pushed onto my NavigationController like:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let view = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsView")
controller.navigationController?.setViewControllers([view], animated: false)
```

When the user then taps on their profile image, the `UIImagePickerController` is presented. Now however, if the user taps on cancel or selects an image, the image controller is dismissed, but so is the user settings controller too. Why exactly is this happening all of a sudden (it was working as expected before the Xcode update).

The code handling the picture selection looks like:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        self.Picture.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        self.Picture.image = pickedImage
        self.PictureChosen = true
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue when present a `UIImagePickerViewController` which parent controller is `UITabBarController`, just set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `overCurrentContext`

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adding a view into the current navigationController right? Why dont you push/present the settingsViewController? 
If you dont push a new controller and call dismissViewControllerAnimated it will close the NavigationController where the view is appended. Or i missunderstand something.

well ... try to push the settingsController

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsView")
controller.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure to understand but, for me, your:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

dismiss the current controller, so the settings one ... no ?

You should do something like this:

```
pickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { _ in
    //Do what you want when picker is dismissed
}
```

Morover, for cancelling action, prefer use:

```
optional func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
```

See @ [UImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerControllerDidCancel:)